# How to trap vbKeyReturn only in VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a `textbox` control in a `subForm` which is a `singleForm`. However, when I press `enter` key it adds a `new record` and the previous `record` hides away. I have the `form property` already set to `current record`.

I used the code below to trap `enter` key, that works.

```
Private Sub txt_1_KeyDown (KeyCode As Intger, Shift as Integer)

Select case KeyCode
    Case vbKeyCode
        KeyCode = 0
        Me.parent.Combo.SetFocus
End Select

End Sub
```

However, now I cannot add a `new line` using `Ctrl + Enter` within the `textbox` since the code fires as soon as I press `enter`. Can someone help how to change the code above so that it only traps `enter` key and keeps the default Access behavior of adding new line on pressing `Ctrl + Enter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a conditional expression testing that:

- The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (ASCII character 13) has been pressed
- The Shift argument of the event handler is zero, indicating no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> have been pressed in conjunction with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

The code might look something like this:

```
Private Sub txt_1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Intger, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 And Shift = 0 Then
        KeyCode = 0
        Me.Parent.Combo.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for the `Shift` argument like this:

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
      If Not Shift = acCtrlMask Then
         MsgBox "Enter"
         KeyCode = 0
         Me.parent.Combo.SetFocus
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy tip. Plz make a slight correction in your code by replacing `vbCtrlMask` with `acCtrlMask`. It works fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for the key code:

```
Private Sub txt_1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Intger, Shift as Integer)

    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyEnter
            KeyCode = 0
            Me.parent.Combo.SetFocus
        Case Else
            ' Leave key code as is.
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I found the answer by @Lee Mac as solution.